# LOL debugging are we? - Stack Overflow homepage alerts false

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

Refreshing the Stack Overflow home page is giving me an `alert('false');`.

Comment: jeah, me too...

Comment: same here, I thought I did something wrong ;)

Comment: It is also appearing for me.

Comment: They're probably telling us to stop incessantly refreshing the question list looking for easy ones.

Comment: Happens at Super User and Server Fault as well. Interestingly enough, not at some of the SE sites, such as WordPress and Web Applications.

Comment: The first question I looked at that triggered this was about MessageBox.  Confusing to put it mildly :)

Comment: You'd think they would have heard of `console.debug()` ;)

Comment: You think they'd heard of testing on a test system, not on the live one.

Comment: Technically it is an `alert(false);`, not `alert('false');`

Comment: @Paul:  Someone checked something into source control, and now has to wear the `DOH!` crown.

Comment: But it appears only on sites where you can see questions...not in a profile or something, perhaps some kind of Java-Script injection?

Comment: @KennyTM They produce a visually identical result: http://jsfiddle.net/VuDnV/

Comment: Fixed now? Or did it just switch to a new ad to display for me?

Comment: It looks like it has to deal with the careers section, which I don't think is on every page.

Comment: Repro on all browsers here (FF3.6,Opera 10.60,Chrome 5,Midori,IE8), logged in and logged out, any action (not just homepage). Note: While the alert() is visible, the ad banners on the right are not yet loaded.

Comment: This was actually a test. On the browsers of those users who are really good, adept programmers - hardcore coding Ninjas! -  it output `true`.

Comment: Technically it is `alert(a)` and `a` just happens to be `false` because there are no `#ninjas` (or they are less than `0`). If there were `#ninjas` and said `#ninjas` were greater than `-1` ... well, I think we all know what that means.

Comment: @Stephen, a plain `console.debug()` is forgotten much easier, and then breaks in all kind of browsers...

Comment: hope it's not a xss attack =)

Comment: @David all real #ninjas are `-1`.

Comment: **Well, what happened?**

Comment: @SLaks: Ninjas, apparently :o)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

This one was my fault.

**UPDATE: Our 5 Why Assessment of the situation**

Problem: there is an alert on every page of Stack Overflow

1. Why?  Because Matt deployed a version of the Careers ad code with a debugging line in it
2. Why?  Because he forgot to remove it before pushing his change
3. Why?  Because he did not eat a nutritious breakfast, which [studies have proven improves school performance](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101130163650AAAkIaP)
4. Why?  Because he moved recently and was preoccupied worrying about his [upcoming commute](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=franklin+ave+%26+gates+ave,+brooklyn&daddr=55+Broadway,+NY&hl=en&geocode=FdrPbAIdOoOX-ynbygH2llvCiTGJet8Y6b5ZTw%3BFR0jbQIdiqeW-yk9bgUuEVrCiTEv4IVIveYbkw&mra=ls&dirflg=r&ttype=dep&date=12%2F09%2F10&time=10:00am&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&sll=40.695875,-73.98433&sspn=0.063709,0.069952&ie=UTF8&z=14&start=0)
5. Why?  Because he got a great deal on an apartment
6. (bonus!) Why?  http://projects.nytimes.com/crime/homicides/map (see: Bedford Stuyvesant)

[Beatings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfuZQ.jpg) will be administered after lunch.

Matt got a badge!
[image]

Comment: But what were you testing?

Comment: @SLaks: For ninjas.  duh.

Comment: Aww.  I wanted to administer my beating before lunch.

Comment: @Jason request approved

Comment: Honestly, it's irresponsible to deploy code that does not check for ninjas.

Comment: Beatings for everybody!!! I want to see the SO office smack down at lunch. How much are tickets?

Comment: @Dillie-O I'm in.

Comment: @Dillie-O @thephpdeveloper I updated the post to include a picture of me with my beating gloves on

Comment: @David Fullerton Yeah! Looks like a good old fashioned street fight!

Comment: Wait, shouldn't he be more worried about assault and battery stats?

Comment: Good luck with the Brooklyn murderers

Comment: Wouldn't that assessment make the correct solution be "reduce crime in New York so there are no more great deals on apartments"?

Comment: At first I was going to yell at SO for playing the blame game, but good to be transparent, Matt (it's ok if it's you confessing, but the team confessing for a dev is always crappy). /n We've all been there, I speak on behalf of the community when I say we forgive you.

Comment: Why is it silver and not gold? Or is it platinum?

Comment: Matt, I live off of Franklin (albeit on the south side of Atlantic, in Crown Heights), but I also get off at the Franklin Ave stop. Since you're a dude, and as long as you don't look lost, you have nothing to worry about. Welcome to the neighborhood! EDIT: for the ladies: my wife also gets off at Franklin sometimes, and she finds that in the somewhat desolate areas around Atlantic, she does get some cat calls. She prefers the shuttle. No bigs.

Comment: That is a bronze badge - and rightly so, after all it was a minor thing. The silver and gold badges are reserved for really bad cock-ups!

Comment: @Felix we decided Gold would only be awarded for actually breaking the site, rather than just making it very annoying to use (as in this case).

Comment: How we got to the end of this discussion without someone renaming the network Smack Exchange is beyond me.

Comment: @David so I take it someone got a gold badge for [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231739/what-happens-when-you-plug-a-ups-into-itself)? That one broke the whole network...

Answer (score 35):

[Do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71786/every-link-i-click-in-so-i-get-a-js-prompt-saying-false)
[you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71798/why-stackoverflow-says-false)
[have](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71792/false-alert-on-opening)
[any](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71793/alertfalse-when-answering-a-question)
[close votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71788/stackoverflow-says-false)
[left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71797/i-get-a-javascript-alert-on-this-certain-question-on-stackoverflow-closed)
[due to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71787/alertfalse-on-all-pages-closed) 
[this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71789/what-does-ninjas-do)
[bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71781/what-is-this-javascript-popup-false-on-stackoverflow)?

[image]

Comment: Hahahahahahahaha.

Comment: Looks like all of them have been deleted.

Comment: Yeah. A bug that exists for 20 minutes doesn't need 11 duplicate questions pointing it out. (Plus, I *think* you get your close votes back. Don't quote me on that.)

Comment: @Michael They do not return. They stick around, such as for the unlikely event that the question gets undeleted then your vote sticks around. There has been a request, though, to refund close votes after a question gets deleted. [This one for self-deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69166/recover-close-votes-if-asker-deletes-his-own-question), but I imagine that mod deletion can also be appropriate.

Comment: @GraceNote - To paraphrase you, `Micheal your close votes return false. They stick around...` ;-)

Comment: @Moshe: *whooshing sound as your joke flies over my head*

Comment: @MichaelMyers - Really?

Answer (score 14):

I'm seeing this too. It appears to be due to the following:

```
<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function(){var g="http://careers.stackoverflow.com/Ad/js",c=location.search=="?golarge",a=location.hash.indexOf("#ninjas")>-1,b="Pretty";(function(){var b="min-height:248px;margin:15px 0",c=$("<div>").addClass("hireme").attr("style",b),a=$("<div>").html(c);document.write(a.html())})();$(function(){alert(a);a&&$("#adzerk1").html("").append($("<div>").attr("id","herebeninjas")).attr("id","stop-adzerk");setTimeout(i,1200);setTimeout(h,300)});var h=function(){c=c||e();a=a||d();b=c?"Large":b;f()},i=function(){var a=$("div.hireme");a.each(function(){$(this).html().replace(" ","").length==0&&$(this).remove()})},e=function(){return $("#careersadsdoublehigh").length>0},d=function(){return $("#herebeninjas").length>0},f=function(){var a=$("<script>").attr("src",j()).attr("type","text/javascript");$("body").append(a)},j=function(){return g+"?style="+b+"&gobanner="+a.toString()}})();
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Prettified: http://pastie.org/1362295.

Answer (score 8):

I wonder if this is the new form of hiring new employees. Put some random bug/feature into the site and see how fast somebody:

- tracks it down
- offers a workaround
- offers a fix
- offers a cool hackish trick that you can do with it.
- all of the above

Too bad I was late to the game seeing it was related to careers! 8^D

Comment: I already thought of that.  However, it doesn't appear to lead anywhere.

Comment: I thought so too, but then I realized that I don't want to work for employers that intentionally annoy me.  So I didn't investigate further.

Comment: @Mark: See Google's PI ad.

Comment: @SLaks ~ Link by chance?

Comment: @drachenstern, @Mark: Sorry, `e`, not `π`. http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=3916173

Comment: and did you manage to repro the bug you were looking for?

Comment: @MarcGravell  Sadly no. I thought I found a glitch on SO, but when I tried to reproduce it here, I couldn't. Sheesh, and here I thought I could go to an old answer of mine and nobody would notice 8^D

Answer (score 4):

Extrapolating on @Rejoice rejoice kbd is back's comment:

```
(function(x) {
    var is_user_awesome = function(y) {
        return check_user_skillz(y) ? 'You Rock!' : 'false';
    };
    alert(is_user_awesome(x));
})(ninjas);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you were looking for something less facetious to add to the five whys, it might involve the fact that JSLint can be set to warn you that you've left alerts() in code before you push to your servers...