# Please allow stackexchange site urls in the Close As Duplicate box

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

Right now, in order to close as duplicate, [one must enter the area51 proposal url in the close as duplicate entry box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81695/cant-mark-proposal-as-duplicate-of-existing-site).

As Stack Exchange sites proliferate, it is often easier to find the site itself once launched, than it is to find the proposal for the site.

**Please allow the site url to be used in the exact duplicate box.**

In other words, the following should work without the terrible, horrible, no good, very bad error:

[image: Screenshot of close box with URL to duplicate site, and error]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this.. site urls should work.

Comment: I believe you mean terrrible horrible no good very bad error.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_and_the_Terrible,_Horrible,_No_Good,_Very_Bad_Day

Comment: @Emmett repro'd...it's the trailing slash that breaks it

Comment: I'm curious, does your office work on some sort of rep-like system? "Okay, @David gets +50 for reproing that error on MSO earlier today, he's in the lead to pick where we order lunch from today."

Comment: @Popular just bragging rights, but that's not a bad idea...oh and lunch is catered every day so we don't get to pick where we order from :\

Comment: @PopularDemand I've been assigning them all brownie points in my head based on who fixes more of the bugs I post/reply to. I'm sure those are redeemable somewhere for something, like Chuck E. Cheese tickets.

Comment: @Popular: We do give out badges sometimes :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71780/lol-debugging-are-we-so-homepage-alerts-false/71810#71810

Comment: @Jason I remember that -- which proves only that I'm too involved on MSO, as if that weren't already obvious -- but since different people were involved I refrained from mentioning it.

Comment: @Tim I'm 75% sure that the scene from the nth _Harry Potter_ movie where there was a point counter on the wall for the different houses or whatever was actually filmed at SOIS's offices.

Comment: They had skateboards in 1972?

Comment: What do you know, they [did](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skateboard). I'd have thought they were a 90s invention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed. The duplicate-of-site popup now supports urls with a trailing slash.