# Careers lists jobs that do not exist -- Testing on production?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

[image: jobs]

Is this the result of someone testing on the production environment? If not, I'd suggest filtering out job listings like "das @ dasd" and "test by matt @kdsk;sdkl;"

Comment: Uh oh. I see a ["test" badge coming](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71780/lol-debugging-are-we-so-homepage-alerts-false) :) although this is arguably a really minor lapse. Stuff like this has happened to me numerous times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the report, Nico.  Matt was testing some stuff in Prod a while ago and the data was hidden. Matt then refactored the "Jobs Near You" section of the homepage on Friday and the data became un-hidden.

The test data will be deleted. Beatings have been scheduled.  A "PublishStatus == 1" badge is being fabricated.

This'll be fixed with the next push.

Comment: Couldn't *we* administer the beatings via that RC robot thingy you guys have?

Comment: @Pekka: Rovio's kind of a weakling in the beating department...we might need some specialized  machinery for this.

Comment: http://www.technovelgy.com/graphics/content06/batting-robot.jpg ?

Comment: @Pekka: YES YES YES.

Comment: +1, we want to see the badge! :)

Comment: mmmmmmmm beatings